# How to move TortoiseHG respository

Tags: tortoisehg

I'm using tortoiseHG 3.0.2 and the repository has been moved due to the folder structure changing. How can I link my local repository to the new location of the central repository?

Answer (score 2):

In your local repository's `.hg\hgrc` file, edit the default path:

```
[paths]
default = http://path.to.central.com:8000
```

You can also edit the `default` path in the `Synchronize` view of TortoiseHg.